# ImportXML Function on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having a tough time pulling info in on Google Sheets using the ImportXML function. I want to pull in the price of a crypto coin so that I have a real-time feed. The link that I'm hoping to pull from is:

https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x40f0e70a7d565985b967bcdb0ba5801994fc2e80

I've tried out a lot of different formulas and keep getting an #N/A or an error. Some of the ones I've tried:

Copy XPATH fully:
=IMPORTXML("https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x40f0e70a7d565985b967bcdb0ba5801994fc2e80","/html/body/app-root/div[3]/div/main/app-uniswap/div/app-pairexplorer/app-layout/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span")

Shortened XPATH (also tried deleting the second backslash before 'li' but that didn't work):
=IMPORTXML("https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x40f0e70a7d565985b967bcdb0ba5801994fc2e80","//li[2]/span")

Include class:
=IMPORTXML("https://www.dextools.io/app/uniswap/pair-explorer/0x40f0e70a7d565985b967bcdb0ba5801994fc2e80","//li[2]/span[@class='ng-tns-c93-2 ng-star-inserted']")

Does anyone have thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

upon disabling JavaScript the site is empty = can't be scraped by Google Sheets by any import formula.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's super helpful. How do you disable JavaScript on a website? Helpful check to do beforehand on future sites. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the problem above, consider using a proper API service that gives you easy access to the data.

For instance you could get Zero price in USD using

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/ZERO/")`

If you need it in comparison to ETH you could try doing it by hand

`=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/ZERO/")/=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/ETH/")`

Or use a more advanced API such as CoinGecko's

https://www.coingecko.com/en/api